# ClassNotFoundException for MessagingException class even though it exists in mail.jar included by Maven

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail, classnotfoundexception

[1]:[Package explorer showing that mail.jar included in maven dependencies indeed has javax.mail.MessagingException class](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BDA2D5899D8E8838%214221)

[2]:[Console output showing that javax.mail.MessagingException is missing](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BDA2D5899D8E8838%214222).

Basically, I have included mail.jar in Maven dependencies and it has MessagingException class as well, but while executing the jar file using Maven, it throws a ClassNotFoundException for the aforementioned class.

Any ideas why that could be happening ?

Comment: which IDE you are using? In Eclipse you need to export your maven dependenies in classpath.

Comment: All ? But once maven deploys a jar file, shouldn't it work standalone ?

Comment: if you go to you project properties -> Build Path -> Order and Export. you will see maven dependency listed there. If it is not checked, then check it and apply. This will add 'all' maven dependencies in eclipse classpath

Comment: thanks for that Adi. I am guessing I will have to set the classpath variable in console same as what my eclipse project is using (and this I guess is inclusive of the classpath used by maven in my project). Do you know a way to extract the classpath entries from an eclipse project ?

Comment: how are you running your application from console?

Comment: try mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="your main class". this will set class path according to your pom.xml